# How to store the echoed values from the database separately?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I used the following PHP code to echo the values from the database:
The following is echoed from the database:

```
BOLERO DI NON AC WHITE BS3
587247
BOLERO DI NON AC SILVER BS3
599524
```

Is it possible to store each one of them separately like

```
var 1=BOLERO DI NON AC WHITE BS3
var 2=587247
var 3=BOLERO DI NON AC SILVER BS3
var 4=599524
```

PHP code:

```
<?php


 $query2="SELECT ABS(price - $new_loan_amount) AS nearest, model, price FROM car_pricing WHERE state = '".$state."' ORDER BY nearest ASC LIMIT 2;
             ";



$result2 = mysqli_query($db,$query2);
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)){

      $i=1;
       echo $database_model = $row['model'];
       echo "<br>";
       echo $database_price = $row['price'];
       echo "<br>";



$i++;
       }
  if (!$result2) { 
     echo("Error, the query could not be executed: " .
     mysqli_error($db) . "</p>");
     mysqli_close($db);
     }

 $query1 = "SELECT state FROM states";
     $result1 = mysqli_query($db,$query1);


?>
```

Comment: You're both storing AND echo'ing the values. The `$database_model = $row['model']` part stores the value in the variable `$database_model` and the `echo ...` part prints it to output.  -- What do you want to do with the values you stored?

Comment: I want to display them separately

Comment: What are you using $i for? I don't see where you actually use it in your while loop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize `$i` outside the loop, otherwise it gets reset every time. And you have to increment it between each `echo`.

```
$i = 1;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
    echo "var $i = {$row['model']}<br>";
    $i++;
    echo "var $i = {$row['price']}<br>";
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: I want it to be reset every time

Comment: Then how will you get `var 3` if you set it back to `1` after printing  the first price and model?

Answer (score 0):

I would

```
echo 'var data = '.json_encode($result2);
```

instead of

```
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)){
   $i=1;
   echo $database_model = $row['model'];
   echo "<br>";
   echo $database_price = $row['price'];
   echo "<br>";
   $i++;
   }
```

Then the javascript variable `data` will contain an array of your results

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically make variables:

```
$i=1;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)){
    ${'var' . $i++} = $row['model'];
    ${'var' . $i++} = $row['price'];
}
```

Then later in your script you ought to have available:

```
echo $var1; // model #1
echo $var2; // price #1
echo $var3; // model #2
echo $var4; // price #2
```

I expect I would do something like this:

```
$i=1;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)){
    ${'model' . $i} = $row['model'];
    ${'price' . $i++} = $row['price'];
}
```

Which gives me:

```
echo $model1; // model #1
echo $price1; // price #1
echo $model2; // model #2
echo $price2; // price #2
```